# A single Postgresql table is not allowing deletes and foreign keys are not working

Tags: postgresql

We have a Postgresql database table with many tables. All of the tables seem to be functioning perfectly except for 1. In the last day or two it has stopped performing row deletes. When we try something simple like

```
delete from bad_table where id_foo = 123;
```

It acts as if it has successfully deleted the row. But when we do

```
select * from bad_table where id_foo = 123;
```

the row is still there.

The same type of queries work fine on all the other tables we tried.

In addition, the foreign keys on this table are not working. There is a foreign key constraint on a column that references a different table. There is an id in the "bad_table", but that id does not exist in the referenced table. Again, foreign key constraints appear to be working fine in all other tables, it is just this one. We tried dropping and recreating the foreign key (which seemed to be successful), but it had no effect.

Between my coworkers and myself we probably have 80 years of relational database experience across oracle, sql server, postgres, etc. and none of us has ever seen anything like this. We've been banging our heads against a wall and are now reaching out to the wider world to see if anyone has any ideas of what we could try. Has anyone else ever seen something like this in Postgres?

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: Are indexes on the table and you tried reindexing them?

Comment: There are triggers on the table. But the triggers are similar to ones we have on other tables and we were able to delete from the table just fine before the past few days. 

There are indices on the table. We have not tried reindexing them. I’ll give that a try.

Comment: I tried reindexing the indexes on the table. It had no affect.

Comment: To your question add: 1) Any recent updates/upgrades to OS and/or Postgres recently? 2) Any changes to database schema? 3) The table definitions for the child and parent tables in the FK relationship. 4) In what client are you doing the queries.

Comment: 1) No 2) No 3)I'll post these separately 4) JetBrains IntelliJ database tool

Comment: 1) **Add the information to the question text** so others don't have to plow through the comments to get relevant information. 2) What happens if you do the delete using `psql`?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the issue with foreign keys was solved by dropping the foreign key constraint and then immediately adding it again.

The issue with not being able to delete rows was fixed by dropping a trigger than was called on row delete and then immediate recreating the same trigger.

I don't know what happened, but it is acting like a constraint and a trigger on that particular table were corrupted.